# Compare array of decimal sum of Integers and exact fractional part

Tags: code-golf, math, functional-programming

Develop a program which takes two arrays of decimal numbers, and compare the sum of whole numbers only and the decimal part. If the sums of the whole numbers are the same, and the decimal parts of Array a are a subset of the decimal parts of Array b, return True. Otherwise, return False.

Example-1 :-

Array a ={2.5,3.0,1.3}

Array b = {5.0,1.0,0.5,0.3}

Sum of whole numbers: Array a = 2+3+1 = 6 and Array b = 5+1 =6 --Matched

Individual fraction part: Array a = 2.5 = 0.5 and Array b = 0.5--Matched

Individual fraction part: Array a = 1.3 = 0.3 and Array b = 0.3--Matched

All the above are matched, so it returns true.

Example-2 :-

Array a ={1.7,2.3}

Array b = {1.2,0.5,2.3}

Sum of the whole numbers: Array a = 2+1 = 3 and Array b = 2+1 =3 --Matched

Individual fraction part: Array a = 1.7 = 0.7 and Array b = 0.2 or .5 or .3 --No Exact match

Individual fraction part: Array a = 2.3 = 0.3 and Array b = 2.3 = 0.3 -Matched
One of the conditions is not matched, so it returns false.

Comment: What is the winning criterion? Is it code golf?

Comment: Yes its code-golf forgot to add it

Comment: Well, add the [tag:code-golf] tag then.

Comment: I'm a little confused, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI `sum(floor(a))==sum(floor(b))` and `filter_nonzeros(fraction_part(a))==some_permutation(filter_nonzeros(fraction_part(b)))` has to be true if I'm correct. @andyra42 Is this correct?

Comment: @randomra OK, I interpreted it a little further, and I think it means 'return `true` if the sum of just the whole numbers and the sum of the decimal parts in `a` are the same as `b`. I'm suggesting this as an edit, to clarify.

Comment: @randomra [My edit is found here.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20706)

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I don't think you're supposed to sum the decimal parts. I think the sum of the integer parts needs to be equal, and the set of fractional parts of a needs to be a subset of the fractional parts of b.

Comment: @orip No, I said that, but it needs to be cleaned up a little. On the bright side, we have our first answer.

Comment: Please use the sandbox for proposed challenges before posting here: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 63 bytes

```javascript
(a,b)=>a.reduce((s,n)=>s+~~(n),0)===b.reduce((s,n)=>s+~~(n),0);
```

### Test it

```js
const x=(a,b)=>a.reduce((s,n)=>s+~~(n),0)===b.reduce((s,n)=>s+~~(n),0);

const A = [2.5, 3.0, 1.3];
const B = [5.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3];

console.log(x(A,B)); // true
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica <s>88</s> 81

This should be easy to beat.
I was surprised that `Rationalize` was needed.

```
r=Rationalize;f=Floor;
(Tr[f@#]==Tr[f@#2] && Complement[r@Mod[#2,1],r@Mod[#, 1]]=={})&
```

---

```
(Tr[f@#]==Tr[f@#2] && Complement[r@Mod[#2,1],r@Mod[#, 1]]=={})& 
@@ {{2.5, 3.0, 1.3}, {5.0, 1.0,0.5, 0.3}}
```

> True

---

```
(Tr[f@#]==Tr[f@#2] && Complement[r@Mod[#2,1],r@Mod[#, 1]]=={})& @@ 
{{1.7, 2.3}, {1.2, 0.5, 2.3}}
```

> False

Comment: You can shorten the `FractionalPart` by using `Mod[n,1]`.

Comment: @LegionMammal978  You're right!  Thanks.

Comment: I think you can save some bytes with Infix and Prefix syntax: `(Tr@f@#==Tr@f@#2&&r@Mod[#2,1]~Complement~r@Mod[#,1]=={})&`

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 45 bytes

```python
x=lambda a,b:sum(map(int,a))==sum(map(int,b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2JzE3KSVRIVEnyaq4NFcjN7FAIzOvRCdRU9PWFlkgSVPz/38A)

Comment: Please put your code in a code block by surrounding it with three backticks on each end.

Comment: Also, anonymous function submissions are allowed, so you can remove the `x=` part to decrease your byte score by 2.